# How does $\ln \frac{1}{2}$ become $-\ln2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How does $\ln \frac{1}{2}$ become $-\ln2$

I just saw a video that said you can transfer the two from the denominator to the numerator, but how does that make the 2 negative? Wouldn't that just make the exponent negative?

For example $\frac{1}{2}$= $2^{-1}$

or am I missing something?

Comment: Note that $e^{-\ln 2}=\frac{1}{e^{\ln 2}}=\frac{1}{2}$...

Comment: $\log a^b = b\log a$, boy. And $\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}$.

Comment: If I may ask, why does this have 3 downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\ln(\frac{1}{2})=\ln(2^{-1})=-\ln(2)$.  Since $2^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}$ and using the log rules for powers.

Comment: Wow! I didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: Another quick question. If I have the following equation $-(5730)k=-\ln2$ To isolate the k, I would divide both sides by -5730. Thus both sides would become positive, right or wrong?

Comment: Yes. $k=\frac{\ln 2}{5730}$ @SunnyBlack

Answer (score 4):

$$\ln\frac{1}{2}=\ln1-\ln2=0-\ln2=-\ln2$$

Comment: This is what I would've done compared to the answers above, but I guess Michael's answer was a lot faster to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule that $\log_{b} a^n=n \log_{b} a$. Since $\log_{b} a^n=\log_{b}(a \times a \times ... \times a)=\log_{b} a+\log_b a+...+\log_{b} a=n \log_b a$